# How to develop a Windows service that runs in the background, waiting for requests?

Tags: windows-services

I want to implement a Web Service that will allow users to store arbitrary data in my home computer and execute arbitrary batch programs to manipulate said data. In order to keep things simple, so I will not deal with priority queues and concurrent processes yet. My process request queue will be a simple FIFO queue.

So, I know how to implement Web Services, and obviously I know how to implement a FIFO queue, but I do not know how to implement a system service that runs in the background, waiting for requests. Where could I find learning resources on how to develop a Windows service?

I already know Windows development using the Windows API, MFC and even some ATL/WTL. (I also know .NET, but I do not like it very much, because it gets in the way how I design programs.) But I would rather not have to deal with COM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're developing a service on Windows and you want to use web services chances are that you will want to host your solution in [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) which is already the type of always-on, background application that you want. E.g. runs all the time regardless of login or UI.

If you use the .NET framework then your implementation will become especially easy due to all the project templates available in Visual Studio.

Here's some CodeProject tutorials:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFPart1.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFWebService.aspx

Comment: @Paul: I did not know that was possible. How do I do that?

Comment: What language and version of visual studio? Btw, you will first have to make sure that you have IIS installed on your system. What OS are you running?

Comment: @Paul: I have VS 2010 Premium. I also have IIS installed. I have Windows 7 Professional x64.

Comment: OK then. All you need to do is create a new project: Language of Choice -> WCF -> WCF Service Application. But, that's just the start. I suggest looking for some tutorials along those lines. Also note that you will need to develop a client, web or desktop based, to consume this service. Well, you don't have to, but it would be nice.

Comment: @Paul: Wait. I have one this very big problem. Some of these batch programs I wrote about are expected to run for several minutes or hours. I don't think a Web Service that processes a request in 30 minutes is a viable thing.

Comment: You don't have to block a service call for that long. And usually should not. For long running operations you should set up a system where you can initiate a script and the poll for its success or failure, and running status actually.